# Bootstrap grid problems (how to solve task)

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm working on a project and can't find a solution how to make this functionality in bootstrap 3 (it should be responsive)..

This is how it should be in PSD:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/62rhH.jpg)
MacBook 15" view here
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BPrFr.jpg)
So what I can't find how to make.
Items in list should be from border to border (see on template 1st image);

Thank you guys, for answer! 
Have a nice day.

Comment: Use the class `.container-fluid` if you need the content to go from border to border, and check how the grid works [here](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid). Also, you have some examples [here](http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#examples) and [here](http://www.bootply.com/121222)

Answer (score 1):

I have some plunk for you: [demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/9cjhoZg2gKZ540GbQSZx?p=preview).

Solution: try using classes like 
`.container` or `.container-fluid` over `.row` division. I hope its help you! Have a nice day!